# How to calculate with the argument of complex numbers in c?

Tags: c

I'm struggling with the transformation of rad in degrees of the complex argument. As result for argument i got 1.25 rad. I want to transform rad in degrees by calculation argument*(180/PI). But as result, I got 0.00 degree and I have no idea why the calculation failed. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* Standard Library of Input and Output */
#include <complex.h>    /* Standard Library of Complex Numbers */

const double PI = 3.141592653589793238;

int main()
{
    double complex z1 = 1.0 + 3.0 * I;

    double complex argument = carg(z1);
    printf("The argument of Z1 = %.2f Rad = %.2f Degree\n", argument, argument*(180/PI));
}
```

Comment: `double complex argument = carg(z1);` ==> `double argument = carg(z1);` ... and **turn on your compiler warnings and mind them**.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a standard library (and as already pointed out by pmg), please refer to the specifications for the prototypes of the functions. Here is an [example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/complex.h/carg):

```
 /* conversion of a real number from its Cartesian to polar form */

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <complex.h>

 int main() {
   double complex z = -4.4 + 3.3 * I;
   double x = creal(z);
   double y = cimag(z);

   double radius = cabs(z);
   double argument = carg(z);

   printf("cartesian(x, y): (%4.1f, %4.1f)\n", x, y);
   printf("polar(r, theta): (%4.1f, %4.1f)\n", radius, argument);
   return 0;
 }
```